# Can't insert values with a click of a button but everything seems to be fine

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Anything wrong whit this code ? Im trying to add values to dataBase by a click of a Button but it keeps getting false, a.k.a not inserted and gives me the toast "Preencha todos os espaços".And it keeps getting me this on stackTrace :

```
   table Exames_table has no column named HORA
```

Although I have this creating column hora :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , DISCIPLINA TEXT , SALA TEXT , DIA TEXT, HORA TEXT)" );
}
```

DateBaseHelper insertData method:

```
   public boolean insertData(String disciplina,String sala,String dia,String hora){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_2,disciplina);
    values.put(COL_3,sala);
    values.put(COL_4,dia);
    values.put(COL_5,hora);
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }else
            return true;


}
```

Method implemented in other activity :

```
      public void addData(){
    add_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData("Portugues", sala_text.getText().toString(), dt, hora2);
                if (isInserted==true){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Teste inserido ao calendario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    date_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hora_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    date_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sala_text.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Preencha todos os espaços",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Not wrong, but: `return result != -1;` is an easier way to write the return in the first method. Also, don't use `if (isInserted==true)`, just use `if (isInserted)`.

Comment: add your stack trace,

Comment: How do I get it?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Exames_table has no column named HORA (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Exames_table(DIA,DISCIPLINA,SALA,HORA) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: And I have this that should create that table whit HORA :  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , DISCIPLINA TEXT , SALA TEXT , DIA TEXT, HORA TEXT)" );
    }

Comment: Do you added HORA column recently..?

Comment: Yes, just saw that was the problem xD im newbie here thanks for your patience

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks bro! Newbie here! Will keep those in mind